# Firefox 38.0.1 throws errors in console with JS and CSS htaccess compression enabled

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, compression, gzip, deflate

I have been working on improving performance on my Wordpress site, one of the things I have done, I switched to dynamic delivery of CSS and JS files (so they are compressed by PHP), which worked very well for performance tests, it seems as though firefox is throwing some errors but the website loads.

Now, I have ALSO added this to the .htaccess in my JS and CSS folder (wp-incldues) on a wordpress site:

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```

for compressing JS and CSS files (since that was flagged in a speed test...), now everything works fine on IE11 and Chrome 43 and on my Android mobile as well, as well as speed test sites, such as http://www.webpagetest.org/ which in fact was recommending to compress those files there..

BUT the bad thing is that the website appears broken in Firefox 38.0.1, it cannot load my menus and Revolution Slider (image carousel).

I've temporarily removed the .htaccess from those folders, speed test in fact flags as a potential for optimisation but at least the website loads properly in firefox now.

here is a collage that shows the errors...https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28979877/FirefoxErrorsCollage.png

any thoughts? the website is www.flower-beach.com

many thanks,
Gabrio

Comment: on the error console you get jQuery is not defined- the strange thing is it happens just when I upload that ,htaccess

I don't get any Revolution slider to load and there's no menu on the website, if you browse the site now you will see menus. if you want I can upload again the .htaccess so you can see it live...thanks